# upgrading to eclipse juno default enterprise version

Tags: java, eclipse

has changed the shortcuts available when right clicking in a project/package.

```
Right click > new > [I now get stuff like "static web project", "message driven bean"]
```

Call me peculair but I want to enable the java defaults, class, enum etc. How can I change what is available ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your eclipse is now in JavaEE prespetive, change your eclipse prespetive to Java then you can see the class,interface etc.